# Running specific test which is part of goal test in Makefile

Tags: perl, testing, makefile, nmake

I'm running "nmake test" and experience 2 failing tests.

Here is the Test Summary Report:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
../lib/File/Copy.t                                              (Wstat: 256 Tests: 466 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  53
  Non-zero exit status: 1
../lib/locale.t                                                 (Wstat: 0 Tests: 660 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  424
Files=2384, Tests=696984, 1309 wallclock secs (73.41 usr +  4.73 sys = 78.14 CPU)
```

How to run these 2 tests without running whole goal?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Those are commands inside of the [Copy.t](https://metacpan.org/source/SHAY/perl-5.22.1/lib/File/Copy.t) file. What you can do is run just the Copy.t with prove and add the `-v` flag to get it to be verbose though, and it will tell you exactly *which one* fails. But there is no way to just run one piece of a .t file.

That would look like this:

```
foo@bar: ~/file-copy $ prove -vl File/Copy.t
```